# Fetch DISTINCT Record with JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to take a distinct patient records and show it in a grid

**Patient Table**

```
PatientId, FirstName, LastName, City
```

**Booking Table**

```
BookingId, PatientId, CategoryId, BookingDate
```

Running below query gives duplicate patient records. This is happening because I have 3 bookings for same patient for different date. This query makes join and brings 3 patient records instead of 1 patient record.

```
 SELECT  DISTINCT PAT.PatientId  
 ,PAT.FirstName
 ,PAT.LastName      

 ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY PAT.PatientId DESC) AS RowNumber 
 INTO #itemSearch  
 FROM  dbo.Patient AS PAT  

 INNER JOIN dbo.Booking AS B  
 ON PAT.PatientId = B.PatientId WHERE  B.CategoryId = 1
```

If I remove this line I get only 1. But I need this temp table for other paging process.

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY PAT.PatientId DESC) AS RowNumber INTO #itemSearch
```

How can I get only 1 patient even though they have 3 bookings?

Comment: Use **Group by PAT.PatientID**

Comment: Because DISTINCT will be executed after ROW_NUMBER() ranking function.

Comment: @AlexanderFedorenko, Oh i see. Is there other alternative?

Comment: look above Dhinakaran Pragasam already responded.

Comment: @AlexanderFedorenko, If i use GROUP By, then i need to add all SELECT  :(columns in Group By

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use GROUP BY clause

```
 SELECT PAT.PatientId  
        ,PAT.FirstName
        ,PAT.LastName      
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY PAT.PatientId DESC) AS RowNumber 
 INTO #itemSearch  
 FROM  dbo.Patient AS PAT  
   INNER JOIN dbo.Booking AS B  
     ON PAT.PatientId = B.PatientId 
 WHERE  B.CategoryId = 1
 GROUP BY PAT.PatientId, PAT.FirstName, PAT.LastName
```

OR use DISTINCT with [DENSE_RANK()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825.aspx) ranking function

```
 SELECT DISTINCT PAT.PatientId  
        ,PAT.FirstName
        ,PAT.LastName      
        ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY PAT.PatientId DESC) AS RowNumber 
 INTO #itemSearch  
 FROM  dbo.Patient AS PAT  
   INNER JOIN dbo.Booking AS B  
     ON PAT.PatientId = B.PatientId 
 WHERE  B.CategoryId = 1
```

Comment: This is really great. Working for me :)